# unsure how to display results // javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok so my code is below. Once the calculate price button is clicked, I want it to display the results beneath the button. ie. the number of cars, type of cars and the price of cars. I know this is probably super easy to do but I just cant get it to work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form name="Cars">
        <h1>Car Sales</h1>
        <p>Which type of car would you like (A, B or C)</p>
        <input type="text" name="CarType"><br>
        <p>how many cars would you like (1-100)</p>
        <input type="text" name="CarNumber"><br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="return beginfunction()">Calculate Price</button>
        <p id="message"></p>
        <script src="car.js">   </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function beginfunction() {
  var CarType = document.forms["Cars"]["CarType"].value;
  var CarNumber = document.forms["Cars"]["CarNumber"].value;
  var CarPrice;
  if ( !( CarType == 'A' || CarType == 'B' || CarType == 'C' ) ) {
    CarTypeError = "Invalid Car Type";
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = CarTypeError;
    return false;

  }


  {
      if (isNaN(CarNumber)) {
        CarNumberError = "Invalid Quantity Entered";
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = CarNumberError;
          return false;
      }

  }
{
  if (CarNumber >0 && CarNumber <10)
  {

  }
  else
  CarError = "Invalid";
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = CarError;
  return false;
}
{
if (CarType == 'A') {
    CarPrice = 30;
} else if (CarType == 'B') {
    CarPrice = 20;
}  else if (CarType == 'C'){
  CarPrice = 10;
}
}

}
```

Comment: `but I just cant get it to work` what error do you get?

Comment: sorry I should have been clearer, the above code works fine. I'm just not sure how to add the lines of code that display the results.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating CarPrice, but you do not use that variable.
You can set it to the same `<p>` tag where you are setting the error messages.
Something like this.

```
if (CarType == 'A') {
    CarPrice = 30;
} else if (CarType == 'B') {
    CarPrice = 20;
}  else if (CarType == 'C'){
  CarPrice = 10;
}
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = CarPrice;
```